# The location of index.html on the Heroku server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I wrote the location of index.html file in the server.js.
But browser shows "Not Found". How can I write  the location of index.html file correctly?

The location of index.html file.

(root)client->public->index.html

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve static assets in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}


const port = process.env.PORT || 5001;
app.listen(port, ()=> console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

I expect browser shows top-page but Heroku logs returns the following line:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html`

Comment: Can you post the folder structuring as well ?

Comment: This is the folder structure. client (node_modules, public, resource, src, gitignore, package.json),  package.json,  Procfile,  server.js

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which I think might be the reason to your problem

1. You have to write res.sendFile('index.html') only because you have declared 'client/build' a public directory so you don't need to enter that path in your app anymore. Just write index.html
2. If thats not the issue maybe you have added the index.html and not added it to the git folder or not committed it. Check that as well

Comment: After I created a repository on github and deployed with that, it worked. Thank you!